# How do I post on click of an image?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I was wondering if it is possible for me to post a name on click of an image to a variable. Like when you have a text field and hit submit and then that variable is posted, I want to do this except on click of an image, display that image. Anyways this is what I tried and I dont get any thing... Any help is appreciated thanks!

```
<html>
<body>
<img src = "img/tumblr_m4zpteBtJu1qm0f2jo1_500.gif" name = "img" method = "post" action = "">
<?php
    $img = $_POST["img"];
    echo "<img src = "$img">";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `echo "<img src = "$img">";`, the image has no input value, so it doesn't workout.

Comment: Please be more descriptive of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @robotsushi I would like to make it so when a image is clicked on it is automaticaly echoed to the screen again.

Comment: You should probably be using jQuery/Javascript to do that. You wouldn't need PHP to do that. Or at least you'd use both, with an Ajax call of somekind. We really do need more insight into what you're trying to do, and why.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You said: 'when a image is clicked on it is automaticaly echoed to the screen'.  If you can click on the image then surely it's already on the screen?  How can you 'echo' an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use

```
<input type="image" src="images/f.jpg" name="submit" />
```

as your submit button

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<input type="image" src="images/yourbuttonimage.jpg" name="submit" />
```

as sumbit button